# Selenium - Select element based on multiple attributes via Xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I did a google Search for the word 'Apple' using Selenium.

Using the below xpath i am trying to get hyperlinks only if the search results that has the word 'Cupertino' in it. But it does return nothing!

```
//a[contains(.,'Apple') and //span/em[contains(.,'Cupertino')]]
```

Google Search Results Screenshot:

[image]

Can someone help me out with correcting the Xpath i used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below XPath

```
//h3[contains(.,'Apple') and following-sibling::div[contains(.,'Cupertino')]]/a
```